# OAuth Authentication Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am doing an iPhone app which requires OAuth 2.0 protocol to be implemented for the login of the user to a particular website.   I have the client id and client secret which i got after registering my application on the website.  I would like to know a few things about this.

1. I saw a number of links regarding this. But yet in my head I'm not very sure of whether i need to use OAuth classes or OAuth consumer classes?
2. Is authentication of the user possible in OAuth without sending the email id and password of the user in a query string?
3. Is is possible to load the website in a uiwebview and login to the website and get the user credentials for the further screen functionalities.

This is the first kind of such an app I'm developing. It would be great if someone could help me out so that i can know clearly how i should go about.

**EDIT:** if there any good tutorials for achieving Login to a website using OAuth please do share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OAuth spec and documentations**

- OAuth 1.0 protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849
- OAuth 2.0 protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
- http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/
- http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

**SDKs for OAuth on iOS**

- YToolkit (OAuth 1.0 & 2.0)

  - [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/sprhawk/ytoolkit)
- OAuthConsumer (OAuth 2.0)

  - [Source on Google Code](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/)
  - [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer)
- LROAuth2Client (OAuth 2.0)

  - [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Client)
  - [Simple document](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/oauth2-for-iphone-and-ipad-applications.html)
  - [Demo project](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Demo)
- MPOAuthConnection (OAuth 1.0)

  - [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/thekarladam/MPOAuth)
  - [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection/w/list)

(Speaking of "a particular website", does it have official or third-party SDK for iOS? If yes then you don't need to implement OAuth authorization yourself.)

Comment: the website has some public apis that we can use. But our clients want features which needs the user's login to get information related to that particular user who has logged in... and in the website they have  not given any information about any ios sdks.....

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good tutorial on [OAuth Tutorial](http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/29/using-oauth-with-twitter-in-cocoa-objective-c/).
This tutorial is a for MAC applications and uses Google OAuthCustomer library. 
OAuthCustomer related readings and source codes can be find within the below URLs

1. [Google OAuthCustomer](https://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer)
2. [Sample Application](https://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer-iphone/)

Make sure to remove non ARC stuff from the OAuthCustomer Library files for iOS applications