# What is the suitable database to be used with ios

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I'm learning to programming IOS using objective c, and now i want to start learning how to connect my apps to the database, however I'm seeing developers separated in two different sides some of them are using SQLite and the others are using MySQL and I'm pretty confused what i have to use, Since I'm a web developer and i can deal with MySQL. In addition of that MySQL can't be used directly we must use Json for that, and the data will be displayed in the browser from what i read, and i tried to search the whole internet for an article that talks about the suitable database for IOS apps i didn't find, so please give me the right answer to follow.

Comment: Do you want internal(Local DB - SQLite,Core Data,Plist and NSUserDefault) or external(MySQL...etc) db?

Comment: It does not matter which CBMS  you use   they all will do the same each one has prons/cons   I will take My Sal over the rest (personal opinion)

Comment: There is no such thing as a suitable database for a given OS. Instead, there are databases more suitable to meet a given set of requirements. As your question is currently formulated, any answer is likely to be based on religious beliefs.

Comment: (also, please try to structure your post. It is extremely difficult to read a 7-line wall of text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose either Sqlite or mySql, it doesn't really effect the performance and you hardly find the time difference using either of these databases unless you are inserting/updating some huge files.

Also, you can use Core-data which is an iOS persistent store. Core-data is an ORM and inside it will use Sqlite and which is much faster than above two.

If you are not familiar with core-data and don't want your efforts to be spent on learning this, then go for Sqlite/mySQL.

Comment: OK, so let's say that i want to monitor the database, and update it from a control panel, for that i will do the control panel on a website. The problem is i saw some examples of Json, the data is displayed on the browser, is that safe? maybe there is some data that i don't want to display it, and if it is readable from the browser people can access it.

Comment: You can add an authentication layer so that your JSON won't display sensitive data if the client is not authenticated. OAuth is a good example of this.

Comment: Yes, you need to add some additional security for data access. There are many options for doing so. You can go with Basic Authentication or Oauth or Single Sign on using Certificates. I'd recommend to add Oauth or certificate based authentication.

Comment: @vikramchowdary if you have any tutorial for this, it will be great and helpful.

Comment: Pls follow this link  [OAuth Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296833/oauth-authentication-iphone), you will be able to find out the required specs and implementation details for OAuth and SDK's which are used for iOS

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Local DB,

```
   SQLite is the best one to use.Why most of us use SQLite database is
       -> It’s lightweight.
       -> It contains an embedded SQL engine, so almost all of your SQL knowledge can be applied.
       -> It works as part of the app itself, and it doesn’t require extra active services.
       -> It’s very reliable.
       -> It’s fast.
       -> It’s fully supported by Apple, as it’s used in both iOS and Mac OS.
       -> It has continuous support by developers in the whole world and new features are always added to it.
```

But if you are going to use external DB

```
         You can use MYSQL,.....
```

Comment: and is the SQLite can be monitored? like MySQL?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: What i'm asking is MYSQL it can be monitored from a control panel, i can see how many user registered the data entered modify it ...etc is the SQLite same thing?

Comment: No.It is not like MySQl

Comment: Great, so i decided to use MySQL, and to do that i need JSON code, what do you suggest to protect my file and don't allow anyone to read it? because as you now the JSON file can be read through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you have a web server then I think you should go with the MySQL-JSON pairing. If you're trying to implement a local database, you should use the CoreData framework.

Answer (score -1):

Suitable Database for iOS app is SQLite .It is an inbuild database for an app.
If you need to get data from API then it's part for server side and for that there is no need to store the data in your app.
If you want to store data locally then you should use SQLite.